# Constructor for factory expecting instance used only in products

Tags: c#, factory

I have a factory that creates products. To do this I need an instance of some other class, that has nothing to do with the actual factory. However all Products should of course use the same instance of it, so I provided that instance to the factory which then passes it to every instance of the `Product`:

```
public class MyFactory
{
    Product CreateProduct(MyClass dependency) 
    {
        return new Product(dependency);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    internal Product(MyClass dependency) { ... }
    public void DoSomething() { /* use the dependency */ }
}
```

However it seems weird to me to provide something to my factory it doesn´t need at all but simply passes to its products.

The other alternative that comes to my mind is to provide the dependency where it´s actually needed, this is the `DoSomething`-method within `Product`. However this would enable users of my API to provide different instances of `MyClass` to different products as shown here:

```
public class Product
{
    public void DoSomething(MyClass dependency) { /* use the dependency */ }
}

...
var dependency1 = new MyClass();
var dependency2 = new MyClass();
myProduct.DoSomething(dependency1);
anotherProduct.DoSomething(dependency2);
```

The question therefore is: **is it okay to provide a dependency to my factory that is actually a dependency for the actual `Product`**?

Comment: Why do you need the same instance of the dependency? that seems an odd need to me

Comment: E.g. because you want to use allways the same database-connection for all products that are created by the factory. However for another factory you could use another connection.

Comment: If it is a responsibility of `MyFactory` to create products with the same `MyClass` instance injected, then `MyFactory` actually also depends on `MyClass`.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau that makes absolutely sense. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did so in a similar scenario: the "products" communicate via the serial port, hence the "factory" had to give the same instance of that serial port (prevent multi-threading issues!) to its products.

In my opinion, the factory should "inject" all the dependencies required by its products into them, thus returning fully functional "products".

Answer (score 2):

I assume the scenario you're imagining is this:

```
public class MyFactory { // preferably this would implement an interface...
    private readonly MyClass _dependency;
    public MyFactory(MyClass dependency) {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
    public Product CreateProduct() {
        return new Product(_dependency);
    }
}
```

This is *exactly* what you should do, at least to the extent that you use a factory class. All that's happening here is you are (manually implementing) function [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying). Let's rewrite this a different way.

```
Func<MyClass, Action<Product>> CreateProduct 
    = (dependency) => () => new Product(dependency);
```

Now

```
var factory = new MyFactory(new MyClass());
var product1 = factory.CreateProduct();
var product2 = factory.CreateProduct();
```

corresponds to

```
var factory = CreateProduct(new MyClass());
var product1 = factory();
var product2 = factory();
```

I'm not saying you should write your code the latter way instead of the former (though I'm not saying you *shouldn't* either).  This is just a model to explain what's going on.  In a language with objects but not higher order functions, the Factory Pattern is just a manual implementation of a [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)).  In functional programming no one talks about the Factory Pattern because it's just a not particularly notable special-case of a ubiquitous aspect of functional programming.

Answer (score -1):

I would store a reference to the IoC container in the factory and use that to create products rather than using the new keyword. The benefits of doing this are that neither the factory or the caller need to know about product dependencies anymore. More importantly the dependencies of products and the dependencies of their dependencies can still use the IoC container. The new keyword in factory pattern tends to break use of IoC.

On the otherhand if you don't need this what you have is better as it is simpler. It's not that weird conceptually that if X is needed to create a product, the factory responsible for creating products also knows about X.

Comment: But your Factory *does* need to know about the IoC container. Your code should *never* know the IoCC exists.

Comment: In particular this doesn´t answer the question at all. My question was not on how the factory might create an instance of `Product`, but how to apply the dependency to that instance.

Comment: If the product is created using the IoC container then the dependency is automatically populated

Comment: "Your code should never know the IoCC exists." The factory is responsible for creating objects, if it doesn't use the IoC container to do that the created objects will not have their dependencies provided by the IoC container. Unless I am missing an alternative?